# Java Desktop.open 2 windows explorers split screen

Tags: java, windows, desktop, explorer

[image: something like this]

I want to open 2 windows explorers side by side.

This opens is, but not split screen:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C:\\Users\\Name\\Videos"));
```

Comment: I doubt it, and even with a copious amount of jni, I’d doubt it

Comment: You'd have a better chance of success by adapting the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784). And by 'adapting' I mean to include the main part of that GUI (the content panel), **twice**, into a parent panel that is then shown in a single window.